# Update class file within a jar nested within an ear from command line

Tags: java, jar

I have an ear deployed on the server.
The ear (say Main.ear) has multiple jars within.
Main.ear
1) Jar1.jar
2) Jar2.jar

Jar1.jar consist of classes which I want to update from command line.

Basically class1.class situated within jar1.jar present in Main.ear

How can that be implemented?

Comment: unpack ear file, unpack.jar replace/update .class file, pack both jar and ear file back

Comment: Or, `x` the one jar from the ear, `u` the class in the jar, `u` that jar in the ear.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to not use x and directly use u in an hierarchical path?